# Change order of breadcrumbs elements in hook hook_system_breadcrumb_alter

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I want to add another element to breadcrumb.
I have:
`Home > Node Title`
I want to add another link between the two elements like:
`Home > Link to view > Node Title`

I have tried with `hook_system_breadcrumb_alter` like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_system_breadcrumb_alter().
 */
function MyModules_system_breadcrumb_alter(Breadcrumb &$breadcrumb, RouteMatchInterface $route_match, array $context) {
  if ( $route_match->getRouteName() === 'entity.node.canonical'){
   $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');
   if ($node instanceof  Drupal\node\Entity\Node && $node->getType() === 'my_node_type'){
     // Get the listing view url.
     $listing_url = Url::fromRoute('view.my_view_id.my_display_id');
     // Add the listing url to breadcrumbs.
     $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Link to view'), $listing_url));
   }
  }
}
```

But i get `Home > Node Title > Link to view` instead of `Home > Link to view > Node Title`
My question is how can i change the order of the last two breadcrumbs elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new breadcrumb instance:

```
$links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();
// change order of $links
$cacheability = \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata::createFromObject($breadcrumb);
$breadcrumb = new \Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb();
$breadcrumb->setLinks($links);
$breadcrumb->addCacheableDependency($cacheability);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.